# Pre hooks in Mongoose Model as ES6 Class

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have defined a mongoose schema and class, but in the pre validate hook, the `this` context is empty. I'm getting `TypeError: this.validateColor is not a function`

### bike.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Mongodb Object Model
// =============================================================================
let BikeSchema = new Schema({
    color: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    wheels: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

// Bike Class
// =============================================================================
class BikeClass {

    validateColor() {
        if(this.color !== 'blue' && this.color != 'red') {
            this.invalidate('Not a valid color');
        }
    }

    validateWheels() {
        if(this.wheels < 2 || this.wheels > 3) {
            this.invalidate('Not a valid number of wheels');
        }
    }
}

BikeSchema.loadClass(BikeClass);

// Do validation checks as API hooks
BikeSchema.pre('validate', next => {
    // Problem: this = {}
    this.validateColor();
    this.validateWheels();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bike', BikeSchema);
```

### index.js

```
const Bike = require('./bike.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bikes');
const db = mongoose.connection;

// Connect to Mongo db
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.debug('Connected to mongo successfully');
    let bike = new Bike();
    bike.color = 'red';
    bike.wheels = 1;
    bike.save()
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use arrow function in Mongoose hooks if you're referring to `this` somewhere in it, because the arrow functions handle `this` in different way than old-fashioned function expression.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): *An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.*

I remember reading somewhere in the Mongoose docs that hooks can only have old-fashioned function expressions, but I can't find it anywhere.

Anyway, just rewrite your hook to something like this

```
BikeSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  // Problem: this = {}
  this.validateColor();
  this.validateWheels();
  next();
});
```

As a side note, because of possible error issues, you should use named function as the hook function, so tomorrow when the error is thrown, you will know exactly in which hook function the code failed.

Comment: Yep arrow functions. :)